# Is this claim correct: `2^{n}−1=Θ(Fibonacci(n+1) - 1)`?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, fibonacci

As a way of simplifying my previous question: [Number of nodes in AVL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69168588/number-of-nodes-in-avl) I want to prove / find a contradiction example to the claim that:

`2^{n}−1=Θ(Fibonacci(n+1) - 1)`

**Note:** Θ (big theta) means both big omega and big O.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not! Beacuse `Fib(n+1) = (((sqrt(5)+1)/2)^{n+1} - ((1-sqrt(5))/2)^{n+1})/sqrt(5)`. Hence, `Fib(n+1) = Theta((1+sqrt(5)/2)^{n+1}`. As `(1+sqrt(5))/2 < 2`, we can conclude that `((1+sqrt(5))/2)^n \in o(2^n)` (little-oh). Therefore, the claim is not correct.